# C# - DataTable Link to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm Working on a c# projet (webform).
Is it possible to Hide the name of the column when I Bind my DataTable to the Gridview ?

This is my DataTable:

```
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|  Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1  |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|  Data 4  |  Data 5  |  Data 6  |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
```

and I would like to reach this in my GridView

```
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|  Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1  |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|  Data 4  |  Data 5  |  Data 6  |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
```

Is it possible and How could I do it please ?

EDIT:

In The First Row,I have many datas which are the same. How Could I join my cells in C# on my DataTable please?

```
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|             Data 1             |             Data 2             |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
|  Data 4  |  Data 5  |  Data 6  |  Data 7  |  Data 8  |  Data 9  |
¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤----------¤
```

I would Like to reach this if possible

Comment: Can you show your grid markup?

Comment: can you share your gridview markup?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the GridView's  ColumnHeadersVisible property to False?

EDIT:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

Comment: I'm a beginner with the webforms and it's excatly what I needs. thanks :)

Comment: In The First Row,I have many datas which are the same. How Could I join my cells in C# on my DataTable please?

Comment: DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
dr.Delete();
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

After that bind your datatable to your grid.

**Edit**

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

    TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();

    cell.Text = "Your text1";

    cell.ColumnSpan = 3;

    row.Controls.Add(cell);    

    cell = new TableHeaderCell();

    cell.ColumnSpan = 3;

    cell.Text = "Your text2";

    row.Controls.Add(cell);

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in web form

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide">
</asp:GridView>
```

in css

```
.hide { display: none; }
```